# jQuery Top of Object Fade In

Tags: jquery, html, fade

I have this code which fades in a div when it is scrolled into view, however it only fades the div in when the whole div is in the viewport.

Is there any way to make it run the fade as soon as the middle of the div comes into the viewport?

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

            }

        }); 

    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think just adding half the height of the div would work:

```
var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + ( $(this).outerHeight() / 2 );
```

To get middle of div instead of bottom. You may want to rename your variables of course.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of bugs with your current code.

Please check the difference between position and [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

```
// middle of object and current viewport
var
    middle = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight() / 2),
    top = $(window).scrollTop(),
    bottom = top + $(window).height()
;
```

Try to move away from using the scroll window event directly:

```
// @see http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/
var scrollHappened = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollHappened = true;
});
setInterval(function() {
    if (scrollHappened) {
        scrollHappened = false;
        checkLazyLoading();
    }
});
```

Also, remove elements that you've already loaded to limit the number of elements checked on the page

```
$(this)
    // remove class, since we're already loading this element
    .removeClass('lazyload')
    // animate to visibile
    .animate({'opacity':'1'}, 500)
;
```

Check the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZbfU/), that has two hidden elements on the page, animated towards visibile when they should be half visible.